# Incomplete string escaping or encoding "\'"

Tags: javascript, build, netlify

I'm currently dealing with issues when running build on Netlify. Seems like the issue doesn't appear on local machine, yet the build fails on Netlify focusing on the following issue:

`Incomplete string escaping or encoding  "\'"`

I've also tried `'\''` that didn't work either.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you're using ``"`` or \`, you should not have to escape the single quote from the string.

Comment: @Quatrecentquatre I've tried using `" ' "` instead, but it throws the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue by using regex instead: `/\'/g`

Comment: You should include an explanation together with your answer